# ¿Es eficiente el método que estoy utilizando para aplicar una función a cada observación de un dataframe mediante procesamiento en paralelo?

Tags: r, funciones, dataframe

Saludos querida comunidad

He definido una función y mi objetivo es aplicar dicha función a cada fila de un dataframe, sin embargo, creo que la forma en la que estoy haciendolo no es muy eficiente.

La función es:

```
acumular <- function(v_list) {
  aux <-  ymd_hms(v_list$fecha_hora)
  
  if( minute(aux) == 05) {
    aux = aux - 300
    
  } else if( minute(aux) == 10) {
    aux = aux - 600
    
  } else if( minute(aux) == 15) {
    aux = aux - 900
    
  } else if( minute(aux) == 20) {
    aux = aux - 1200
    
  } else if( minute(aux) == 25) {
    aux = aux - 1500
    
  } else if( minute(aux) == 35) {
    aux = aux - 300
    
  } else if( minute(aux) == 40) {
    aux = aux - 600
    
  } else if( minute(aux) == 45) {
    aux = aux - 900
    
  } else if( minute(aux) == 50) {
    aux = aux - 1200
    
  } else if( minute(aux) == 55) {
    aux = aux - 1500
    
  } 
  
  if(is.na(v_list$precipitacion) == TRUE ) {
    v_list$precipitacion = 0
  }
  
  aux <- v_list %>%
    transmute(codigo_estacion, fecha_hora = aux, precipitacion = precipitacion)
  
  return(aux)
}
```

Y el dataframe al que deseo aplicar esta función es el siguiente:

```
> str(subset_UCA)
'data.frame':   8928 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ codigo_estacion: num  86209 86209 86209 86209 86209 ...
 $ fecha_hora     : chr  "2017-12-01 00:00:00" "2017-12-01 00:05:00" "2017-12-01 00:10:00" "2017-12-01 00:15:00" ...
 $ precipitacion  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Mi objetivo es utilizar parLapply para aplicar la función a cada fila del dataframe realizando un procesamiento en paralelo. Ya que luego trabajaré con dataframes de mayores dimensiones al del ejemplo aquí presente y creo me ahorrará bastante tiempo de procesamiento.

Lo primero que hago es crear una lista de dataframes a partir de **subset_UCA**:

```
ldf_subset_UCA <- lapply(as.list(1:dim(subset_UCA)[1]), function(x) subset_UCA[x[1], ])
```

De esta manera obtengo una lista **ldf_subset_uca** compuesta de dataframes, donde cada uno de los cuales tiene solo una observación; correspondiente a cada fila del dataframe **subset_UCA**

```
> str(ldf_subset_UCA[[1]])
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ codigo_estacion: num 86209
 $ fecha_hora     : chr "2017-12-01 00:00:00"
 $ precipitacion  : num 0
```

Luego utilizo parLapply para aplicar la función a cada elemento de **ldf_subset_UCA**

```
cl <- makeCluster(4)
clusterExport(cl, c("ldf_subset_UCA", "acumular"))
clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(lubridate); library(dplyr)})

convert <- parLapply(cl, ldf_subset_UCA, acumular) 

stopCluster(cl)
```

El resultado es la lista **convert** en donde se ha aplicao la función acumular a cada elemento, pero como mi objetivo es obtener un dataframe realizo el siguiente y último paso:

```
subset_UCA <- do.call("rbind", convert)
```

Ahora **subset_UCA** es una dataframe en donde se ha aplicado la función **acumular** a cada fila.

Me parece que este proceso es ineficiente y me pregunto si hay una mejor forma de aplicar la función **acumular** a cada fila de **subset_UCA**.

subset_UCA antes del proceso:

```
> tail(subset_UCA)
     codigo_estacion          fecha_hora precipitacion
8923           86209 2017-12-31 23:30:00             0
8924           86209 2017-12-31 23:35:00             0
8925           86209 2017-12-31 23:40:00             0
8926           86209 2017-12-31 23:45:00             0
8927           86209 2017-12-31 23:50:00             0
8928           86209 2017-12-31 23:55:00             0
```

subset_UCA luego del proceso:

```
> tail(subset_UCA)
     codigo_estacion           fecha_hora precipitacion
8923           86209 2017-12-31 23:30:00             0
8924           86209 2017-12-31 23:30:00             0
8925           86209 2017-12-31 23:30:00             0
8926           86209 2017-12-31 23:30:00             0
8927           86209 2017-12-31 23:30:00             0
8928           86209 2017-12-31 23:30:00             0
```

Nótese los cambios en la varibale fecha_hora

Comment: una duda. ¿Lo que buscas es obtener la el obejto `datetime` con todos los minutos normalizados a 00? Si es así puse una respuesta que te podría ayudar. Usa la vectorización de R en lugar de la iteración paralela, para tu caso creo que es mejor opción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, me parece que sería muy ineficiente y crecientemente ineficiente a medida que aumenta el número de filas. Paralelizar suele ser una buena alternativa cuando la función que estás utilizando tiene un tiempo de ejecución largo (ajustar un modelo complejo, cosas por el estilo). En ese¡os casos el overhead de la paralelización es un costo relativamente bajo con respecto a la mejora por paralelización. En tu caso `acumular()` debería tener un tiempo de ejecución trivial para cada fila/elemento del vector, y al paralelizarlo obligas a `R` a crear un nuevo proceso, exportar librerías, procesar y después reunir todos los resultados en una lista. El tiempo que lleva hacer todo eso para cada fila debe estar a 3 o 4 ordenes de magnitud con respecto a lo que demora `acumular()`.

En `R` no suele ser buena idea paralelizar operaciones en vectores (las columnas de tus  data.frame son vectores) porque es precisamente vectorizado y ya está optimizado para ese tipo de operaciones.

Ahora bien, leyendo tu código y a menos que haya entendido muy mal tu pregunta lo que buscas es pasar `fecha_hora` a la base de hora, es decir,  que el minuto sea siempre 00. Hay una función en `lubridate` que hace exactamente eso, es `floor_date().

Va un ejemplo:

```
#Recreo tus datos: 

read.table(text = "codigo_estacion fecha hora precipitacion
8923 86209 2017-12-31 23:30:00             0
8924 86209 2017-12-31 23:35:00             0
8925 86209 2017-12-31 23:40:00             0
8926 86209 2017-12-31 23:45:00             0
8927 86209 2017-12-31 23:50:00             0
8928 86209 2017-12-31 23:55:00             0", header = T) -> foo

#Tengo unir fecha/hora porque si no me daba problemas read.table
foo %>% unite(col = "fecha_hora", fecha, hora, sep = " ") -> foo

foo %>% 
  mutate(base_hora = floor_date(ymd_hms(fecha_hora), "hour"))
```

La última línea hace el trabajo: `floor_date(.date, "hour")` regresa la fecha con los minutos en cero. La hora, día, etc. quedan igual.

Aunque no he hecho un benchmark no dudo que sea más rápido que tu función `acumular()`, porque en lugar de evaluar 10 condicionales (algo relativamente lento) trunca directamente el objeto datetime.

Si el data.frame real con el que estás trabajando es **larguísimo** quizás puedas ganar algo paralelizando, pero no por cada fila sino dividiendo al data.frame en 2, 4, 6 u 8 partes (dependiendo de los cores físicos que tengas) y aplicar la función a cada parte para después reunirlo. Aún así no estaría seguro de las ventajas de paralelizar. Quizás podrías explorar alguna de la librerías de R para time series (`tsibble` para algunas cosas, `slider` para trabajar sobre ventanas de tiempo). Esas librerías tienen funciones escritas en `C++` que son más rápidas que el código de R.